# Screen Lagging in Scroll view

Tags: react-native

screen lagging while scrolling in parallax scroll view

I have tried Using Animated API and Onscroll event using useNativeDriver  to true nothing seems to work for me

While scrolling up , view is bit lagging and scrolling is also not smooth

Comment: have you tried using your app in a release build? because sometimes console operation puts heavy loads on app.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)